# CodeIgniter Escaping Clean URLs adding index.php/

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've setup clean URLs on CodeIgniter through .htaccess and they work fine. Sometimes though CI seems to escape it's clean urls and go back to index.php/ urls. So far I've tracked it down to either:

- Forms
- Redirects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using  `mod_rewrite` to remove `index.php` from url. You need to change in `config` file also to make in redirect or from, urls aren't using `index.php`. You need change in `config.php` from `$config['index_page'] = "index.php";  to $config['index_page'] = "";`.

Please check the comments in config files above that line :)

Answer (score 2):

On line 29, in **config.php** file:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

remove the index.php, so it looks like:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```